Does anyone know how I can keep my drop down menus open when a button is clicked?
I'm in the middle of learning JS so I'm new to it and self-learning. When I click the dropdown buttons my buttons don't stay active and open for half a second and close again. would anybody be able to walk me through how I can keep them open with JS? Here is my code so far! would appreciate the help! I didn't know a project by the way so that's why it's on Elon Musk lol.
let menu_icons = document.querySelector('.menu-icons'),
nav = document.querySelector('nav');

menu_icons.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('active');
});

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#fullscreen-video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    scale: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -10;
  }
  
  #fullscreen-video-container video {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

img {
    top: 5px;
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    
  }
:root {
    --main-color: rgb(228, 145, 37);
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}

body::before {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100vh;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
 
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-icons {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    /* display: none; */
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -ms-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -o-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
   
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
}


.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    -webkit-transition: color 650ms;
    -moz-transition: color 650ms;
    -ms-transition: color 650ms;
    -o-transition: color 650ms;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}

.nav-list a:active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -ms-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -o-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -ms-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid var(--main-color);
    background-color: #ff2222;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1.2rem solid var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--main-color);
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}


.nav-list li:active>.sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:active>.sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
}

@media screen  and (max-width: 900px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #191919;
        z-index: 1000;
        align-items: initial;
        display: none;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 50%;
        right: 0;
    }

    .nav-list > li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }

    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 0.4rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }

    .sub-menu .sub-menu {
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 0.4rem;
    }

    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-list li:active > .sub-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }

    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }

    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }

    .fa-times {
        display: none;
    }

    nav.active .fa-times {
        display: block;
    }

    nav.active .fa-bars {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display: flex;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSS/test.css') }}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                   <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="logo"><img class="logo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Images/logo2.png') }}"></a>

                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">ELON MUSK</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">THROUGH TIME</a>
              </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">ELON ODYSSEY <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">SPACE X</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#">NEUROLINK</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">TESLA</a>
                          </li>
                          
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                   
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">MORE
                            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">DOGE</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">FORUMS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">BLOGS</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    
  
                </ul>
                
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="fullscreen-video-container">
      <video autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/Videos/Background.mp4') }}">
      </video>
  </div>

      
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>


When I run the code snippet you've posted and then click on the faint grey burger menu in the upper right, the menu stays open (showing home, elon musk, etc.). Is that not the behavior you're seeing when you click it?

@Rocky Sims The problem is when clicking on ELON ODYSSEY and MORE in the menu.

You're pretty close. You need to change .nav-list li:active > .sub-menu to .nav-list li.active > .sub-menu and add some js to toggle the active class when a menu item is clicked:
let menu_lis = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list li');
for (let menu_li of menu_lis) {
  menu_li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu_li.classList.toggle('active');
  });
  
}

Here is a working example snippet.


let menu_icons = document.querySelector('.menu-icons');
let nav = document.querySelector('nav');

menu_icons.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('active');
});

let menu_lis = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list li');
for (let menu_li of menu_lis) {
  menu_li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu_li.classList.toggle('active');
  });
  
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#fullscreen-video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    scale: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -10;
  }
  
  #fullscreen-video-container video {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

img {
    top: 5px;
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    
  }
:root {
    --main-color: rgb(228, 145, 37);
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}

body::before {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100vh;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
 
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-icons {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    /* display: none; */
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -ms-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -o-border-radius: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
   
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
}


.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    -webkit-transition: color 650ms;
    -moz-transition: color 650ms;
    -ms-transition: color 650ms;
    -o-transition: color 650ms;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}

.nav-list a:active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -ms-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -o-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -ms-transition: background-color 650ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid var(--main-color);
    background-color: #ff2222;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1.2rem solid var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: var(--main-color);
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--main-color);
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}


.nav-list li:active>.sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:active>.sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
}

@media screen  and (max-width: 900px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #191919;
        z-index: 1000;
        align-items: initial;
        display: none;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 50%;
        right: 0;
    }

    .nav-list > li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }

    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 0.4rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }

    .sub-menu .sub-menu {
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 0.4rem;
    }

    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-list li.active > .sub-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }

    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }

    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }

    .fa-times {
        display: none;
    }

    nav.active .fa-times {
        display: block;
    }

    nav.active .fa-bars {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display: flex;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSS/test.css') }}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                   <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="logo"><img class="logo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Images/logo2.png') }}"></a>

                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">ELON MUSK</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">THROUGH TIME</a>
              </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">ELON ODYSSEY <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">SPACE X</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#">NEUROLINK</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">TESLA</a>
                          </li>
                          
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                   
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">MORE
                            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">DOGE</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">FORUMS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">BLOGS</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    
  
                </ul>
                
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="fullscreen-video-container">
      <video autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/Videos/Background.mp4') }}">
      </video>
  </div>

      
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>



